# Creating an R function: all the parts work, fails when assembled

Tags: r, function

I have this awfully long but not too novel script to put a decimal point somewhere between a string of numbers. I would like to turn it into a function. The individual "steps" work exactly like the correlating scripts; however, when I try to put together the parts it would not change anything in the numbers. Can you please help me out with this?

```
library(stringr)

num_set <- c(0:1001)
# whole code
num_set[which((nchar(num_set) == 3) & str_sub(num_set, 1, 2) < 12)] <- str_c(str_sub(num_set[which((nchar(num_set) == 3) & str_sub(num_set, 1, 2) < 12)], 1, 2), str_sub(numset[which((nchar(num_set) == 3) & str_sub(num_set, 1, 2) < 12)], 3, 3), sep = ".")
#A:
num_set[which((nchar(num_set) == 3) & str_sub(num_set, 1, 2) < 12)]
#B:
str_sub(num_set[which((nchar(num_set) == 3) & str_sub(num_set, 1, 2) < 12)], 1, 2)
#C:
str_sub(num_set[which((nchar(num_set) == 3) & str_sub(num_set, 1, 2) < 12)], 3, 3)

rep_a <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < z)]
}
rep_a(num_set, 3, 2, 12)

rep_b <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  str_sub(w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < z)], 1, y)
}
rep_b(num_set, 3, 2, 12)

rep_c <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  str_sub(w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < 12)], y + 1, 4)
}
rep_c(num_set, 3, 2 ,12)

rep_whole <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < z)] <- str_c(str_sub(w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < z)], 1, y), str_sub(w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < 12)], y + 1, 4), sep = ".")
}
rep_whole(num_set, 3, 2, 12)
```

Thank you!

Comment: forgot to include the merging of step C and D:

`rep_d <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  str_c(str_sub(w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < z)], 1, y), str_sub(w[which((nchar(w) == x) & str_sub(w, 1, y) < 12)], y + 1, 4), sep = ".")
}

rep_d(num_set, 3, 2, 12)`

Comment: Your function should return w.

Comment: Hi @Roland , thank you for your answer. It does indeed. What I fail to comprehend is that it follows the form of the original code that returns numbers 100 - 120 as "10.0", "10.1", "10.2" etc. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It should but it doesn't. Add return(w).

Comment: Ahhaaaa, i get it now! Amazing, thank you very much for your time and effort!